# Turning automatic placing of tables/figures off

Tags: tables, floats

I have noticed that table or figure is sometimes (I haven't figured the pattern yet) automatically placed before its reference, regardless of the code and `[!h]` (or `[!ht]`). Is it possible to turn this off? Better said, can I stop LaTeX playing with MY figures and tables (and do everything manually)?

Comment: This can be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/3954 . To answer your question, one option would be to use static objects (instead of floats) such as `minipage`s and provide a caption using `\captionof` from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages.

Comment: Just expanding a little: `table`s and `figure`s are *meant* to float. By using those environments, you are explicitly *asking* TeX to work out the best place to put them. That placement can be influenced but TeX will ultimately make the decision. If you don't want TeX to move them, don't use those environments. Use e.g. `tabular` or whatever instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using `minipage`s or simply using `\includegraphics` and adding `\caption` using `\captionof{figure}{Caption text}` from either `caption` or `capt-of` package (both provide that macro) is a good idea, you can take shelter under the `H` position specifier of `float` package. `[H]` removes the floating nature of floats.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,kantlipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
  Figure~\ref{fig:myfig} referred here.
  \kant[1-2]
  \begin{figure}[H]%[t]  %% change to [t] and see the difference
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{My figure}\label{fig:myfig}
  \end{figure}
  \kant

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note there is `flafter` package that ensures the floats appear after they are first referred in text (to some extent). You have to add `\usepackage{flafter}` in your preamble.